# Releasing NSString object

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I`m working with iOS SDK

If I have

```
NSString *str = @"Something cool";
NSLog(@"Text : %@", str);
```

Should I use

```
[str release];
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.

> Creating Strings
>
> The simplest way to create a string
>   object in source code is to use the
>   Objective-C @"..." construct:
>
> NSString *temp = @"/tmp/scratch"; Note
>   that, when creating a string constant
>   in this fashion, you should avoid
>   using anything but 7-bit ASCII
>   characters. Such an object is created
>   at compile time and exists throughout
>   your program’s execution. The compiler
>   makes such object constants unique on
>   a per-module basis, and they’re never
>   deallocated, though you can retain and
>   release them as you do any other
>   object. You can also send messages
>   directly to a string constant as you
>   do any other string:
>
> BOOL same = [@"comparison"
>   isEqualToString:myString];

Comment: If I use 
dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@”foo”, @”bar”, @”baz” forKeys:@”one”, @”two”, @”three”
count:3];
It is not necessary to release it, because it is factory method, not an object, right ?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's an auto-release object.
You should only release an object the you allocate `[[NSString alloc] init]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an autoreleasepool (iOS applications usually do) you don't have to release the instance.

Comment: Usually you have to release objects which you are responsible for - that means you're the owner. According to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB this is the case for an object you create using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

Answer (score 0):

No. You only need to consider to release an object when you use alloc.